# How to delete file when application is closed

Tags: java, android, file, ondestroy

I want to delete a file when my app is closed. I perform the deletion in the `onDestroy` method of my activity. But when I check to see if the file is deleted, after closing the app, the file is still there.

Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "fileName.txt");
    if(file.exists()){
        file.delete();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

EDIT: Asked to show snippet of code regarding the creation of a temp file:

```
try {
        file = File.createTempFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29

Comment: In Java you could create a temp file:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16691560/4065876.  I don't know if in Android this works.

Comment: @Kenney, I replaced my `delete()` method with `deleteOnExit()`, but it did not work.

Comment: Did you checked whether the control goes inside  if(file.exists()){ ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari, I did check, it didn't work. Because `onDestroy` method is not reliable. Let me try using the temp file way first.

Comment: @Kenney [_Note that on Android, the application lifecycle does not include VM termination, so calling this method will not ensure that files are deleted_](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit())

Comment: Have you checked whether your `onDestroy` method is called? I bet you could find all the methods you need to override [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). (@AleksandrMedvedev thanks ;-))

Comment: why dont u copy the content of file into variable and delete the file instantly?

Comment: @Lokanath, that's possible, but more complexity than needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not rely on `onDestroy` method to be called (the system can interrupt your process before the lifecycle will reach this stage).
I would suggest you use temporary folders to keep such a file, but it is still your responsibility to keep the size of temp files within reasonable limits (~1 mb).

---

**UPDATE** (in relation to the temp-file snippet) 
You are trying to provide a full path to `ExternalStorageDirectory` as a file-name prefix.
But this approach is a bit different. The `File.createTempFile` function does nothing except creating a file in a special temp-file directory using random name. Thus, it is still our responsibility to provide a temp-folder, letting the system know that this file is appropriate to delete:

```
public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
    File file;
    try {
        String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
        file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
    catch (IOException e) {
        // Error while creating file
    }
    return file;
}
```

The `cachedDir` is internal storage, which means that other apps cannot write files here, so you should implement [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to provide a URI of your temporary file.

Comment: temp file seems to be promising, however, I don't think I can use a temp file since I am using the files as pictures taken by a camera `service`

Comment: Why do you think you can't?

Comment: I was getting a null exception error when the camera service was writing the image byte array to that file, the file was indeed created as a temp file

Comment: Could you provide your code snippet where you are creating a file?

Answer (score 0):

I spotted a couple of potential issues with the way you were creating a file, especially since you want to delete them. You might as well store the files in the local cache for your app, in this way.

```
// get the cache directory for our present `Activity`; 
// referred to by `context`
File directory = context.getCacheDir(); 

File file = File.createTempFile("prefix", "extension", directory);
```

[[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)] The files will be private to your app, and if the device is low on storage, Android can get rid of them. Although you should not depend on this.

You might want to take a look at the [`Android Activity Life-cycle`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk8de.png). So, if you keep a track of the files you have created in a session. Get rid of these files in your `onDestroy()`. I would suggest saving this list as a `SharedPref` or something. Reason? That `onDestroy()` is not the most dependable thing on the planet. If you have the files saved, you can delete them on the next time `onDestroy()` is called (if they still exist).

Personally, I would probably not use `onDestroy()` for this purpose. Maybe an `onStop()` is more dependable. Its your design, and you will be the best judge. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) . You may override `onTerminate()` to delete your file.

Comment: From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate()):
`This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so.`