# Delete file on closing - JavaFX

Tags: file, pdf, javafx, converters, delete-file

I'm making a JavaFX application which can open Word, Excel, and PowerPoint files by converting them to a PDF. When I close the application, I don't need the converted PDF anymore. Can I delete the PDF when I close the application?

Comment: So this is a yes/no question? Unless the PDF is still open, the answer should be "yes".

Comment: pdf will be open in application so when close application pdf should be deleted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691437/when-are-java-temporary-files-deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the Application's [`stop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop()) method and the File's [`delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html) method. Override the `stop` method and delete the File in that method.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the info! I probably should've read the question better. I have changed the answer now so that it responds to the Application closing rather than the Stage closing.

Comment: @James_D you may want to use `deleteOnExit()` which will delete the file when the JVM stops. However if you have already used the `stop` method together with `delete` it should work as well

Comment: I tried with 'deleteOnExit()' but that don't work i will try does this work, thank you