# Filename with screenshot[SomeRandomnumber.png] is created inside var/tmp while using selenium - java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I am taking screenshot in my selenium project using below method

```
public String getScreenShotUrl(String fileName, Information information) {
    final String screenShotS3FolderName = "/test/s3"
    final String apiHistoryScreenshotUrl = "/test/history"
    new Thread(() -> {
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) information.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        contentHandler.moveScreenshotImageFileToS3(fileName, screenShotS3FolderName, screenshot);
    }).start();
    String crawlScreenshotUrl = apiHistoryScreenshotUrl + fileName + DOT_JPEG_FILE_EXTENSION;
    information.getAllScreenShotUrls().add(screenshotUrl);
    return crawlScreenshotUrl;
}
```

I am not storing file any where inside var/tmp foler

I am using firefox 83

geco driver : 28

os : linux

Problem :

I am seeing lot of png files inside

```
/var/tmp

screenshot18218906458183251330.png
```

Now sure what is triggering this screenshot in my firefox/selenium.

This is filling my hard-disk. How do i stop firefox from taking this screenshot.

Not sure which command is triggering this . I recently upgraded to firefox-83 but not sure 83 is reason for this issue

Comment: As you are using OutputType.FILE . Its creating file in temp folder .As per comment  in code "Obtain the screenshot into a temporary file that will be deleted once the JVM exits. It is up to users to make a copy of this file" . you may need to write something to clean the tmp folder. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16691560/5324105

Comment: Makes sense i am running a server so jvm may not be shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Rahul command i added delete command explicily . this solved the problem
Adding screenshot.delete() // This delete the file explicitly without waiting for jvm to exit

```
public String getScreenShotUrl(String fileName, Information information) {
    final String screenShotS3FolderName = "/test/s3"
    final String apiHistoryScreenshotUrl = "/test/history"
    new Thread(() -> {
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) information.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        contentHandler.moveScreenshotImageFileToS3(fileName, screenShotS3FolderName, screenshot);
        screenshot.delete() // This delete the file once it is moved to s3
    }).start();
    String crawlScreenshotUrl = apiHistoryScreenshotUrl + fileName + DOT_JPEG_FILE_EXTENSION;
    information.getAllScreenShotUrls().add(screenshotUrl);
    return crawlScreenshotUrl;
}
```