# Unable to locate file in a /tmp/ directory generated in a Spring boot application deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I am working with a spring boot application, which is deployed on a Kubernetes cluster. Here, the problem I am facing is as follows:

In my application, I am capturing the response to an external API call in the following fie:

```
File stateFile = File.createTempFile(StringUtils.join(documentId, "_", DOCUMENT_STATE),
        FILE_PATH_SUFFIX);
```

In the application log, I find that the file name is generated as follows: `/tmp/b6bcc625-8daa-47a5-b403-c99569ab90b8_documentState13641944363587554481.json`

But, while I am logging into the pod, I cannot find the file in `/tmp/` directory of the given pod. I am not able to comprehend what is going on here. Could anyone please help here ?

Comment: It's hard to tell giver your snippet because we can't see how do you process this file after, do you delete it? If you do, how exactly? You may be hitting behavior, explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694493/3066081 , when you unlink file, but process still holds the handle and able to use it. Also, how do you "logging into pod", do you `kubectl exec` into it?

Comment: I do agree with the Andrew comment. Also, please attach the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you save a file in this location directly ( in `/tmp` in the `Pod`)?